# Is it possible to create my virtual host folder in wamp outside of the www directory

Tags: localhost, virtualhost, wampserver

I am using wampserver 3.1.0 64 bit and I want to have a virtual host in "C:\Node"

I have tried the "Add a Virtual Host" option using the following:
Name of the Virtual Host: Node
Complete absolute path of the VirtualHost folder: C:\Node

But it returns an error.

How can I achieve this successfully?

Thank you!

Comment: That should not be a problem. What error

Comment: Thank you! I have resolved the problem. I found out that my antivirus program was preventing changes to the host file.